# Adding off click and esc to close slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a panel that slides up and pushes content upwards. I'd like to be able to close it using an off click or pressing esc. I've tried adding `e.stopPropagation();` and `if (e.keyCode == 27) {`

*EDIT* Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqc77g1f/2/

Here is a fiddle that has off click: http://jsfiddle.net/yKhfP/

```
    $("#toggle").click(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { // esc keycode
    if ($('#panel').css('display') == 'block') {
        var height = '-=' + $('#panel').height();
    } else {
        var height = '+=' + $('#panel').height();
    }
      e.stopPropagation();
    $("#panel").slideToggle((2300), "easeOutQuint");

    $(".project_wrap").animate({
        bottom: height
    }, (2300), "easeOutQuint")
    $('html, body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

Comment: It would help to post a working JSFiddle demo so we can play around with the code.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister updated OP :)

Answer (score 0):

for escape:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       if($('#panel').css === 'block'){
         $('#panel').hide(200)
       }
    }
});
```

Look into perhaps $.blur for the "off click"